# jstl not executeing within jsp file loaded using jquery load()

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp

i have partial jsp file with jstl code :

```
 <%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
    <form method="POST" action="EntrerClient" id="submitparticulier" 
 class=submitparticulier">
 <fieldset>
 <input type="hidden" id="Id" name="idform" value="inscp">
 <select name="genre" class="genre">
 <option>Monsieur</option>
 <option>Melle/Madame</option>
 </select>
 </br>
 <label for="etat">Nom <span class="requis">*</span></label></br>
 <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" value="<c:out      
 value="${particulier.getNom()}"/>" size="20" maxlength="60" />
 <span class="erreur">${form.erreurs['nom']}</span>
 <br />
 <p class="${empty form.erreurs ? 'succes' : 
 'erreur'}">${form.resultat}</p>
 <br />
 <p id="adcli"><a href='#ADCLI'>Valider</a></p>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
```

and principal jsp :

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1 
/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="ressources/_javasctipt.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    constructform("<c:out value="${param['par']}"/>");
    </script>
...
```

the partial file is loaded using jquery :

```
...
function constructform(param) {
var principal = $("#Gc_FenettrePrincipale");
principal.empty();
principal.append("<div class=\"Gc_FenettreSec\" id=\"_ADD\"><p>Ajout 
Clients</p></div>");
 principal.append("<div style=\"width:700px;padding:20px;S\">");
 principal.append("<div id=\"ajout_client\" class=\"ajout_client\">");
 principal.append("</div></div>");
 var add=$("#add");
    add.removeClass('current');
        $("#adcli").addClass('current');
        $('#ajout_client.div').remove();
        var form_particulier=$("<div/>");
        form_particulier.load("ressources/PaletParticulier.jsp");
        //form_particulier.html();
        var formul = $("#ajout_client");
        formul.append("<select name=\"type\" class=\"type
 \"><option>Particulier</option><option>Organisme</option></select>");
        formul.append(form_particulier);

}     ...
```

the

```
      <input type="text" id="nom" name="nom" value="<c:out      
 value="${particulier.getNom()}"/>"
```

servlet call 
    ...

```
request.setAttribute(ATT_FORM,form);                    
request.setAttribute(ATT_PARTICULIER,particulier);               
response.setContentType("text/html");        
this.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(VUE).forward(request, 
 response);
```

in the partial jsp does not work but it work in the principal jsp if used,i can't figure why
in the java channel in the irc thy suggeced to go to jsf,i can't to that now,am off of deley

Comment: Possibly `class` is not available in scope for partial.jsp. Also check if `EL` is not ignored for that given jsp.

Comment: EL ??? what is it

Comment: @AbdouDadou Anything between `${` and `}` is an expression. The language used for expressions in a JSP is called "[JSP Expression Language](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html)" or EL for short *(imaginative, right?)*.

Comment: `class` is a [reserved word](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4019252/5221149) in EL, so name it something else.

Comment: no,ibn reality the name is not class ,it is just an exmple,i'v changed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i figured out that load() function is http resquet,GET or POST ,and am using servlet to load jsp,so the soution is to create the hol jsp.
i don't see better solution
"an other servlet or an other jsp"

Answer (score 0):

Idea 1: If your JavaScript function `constructform` is in `/ressources/_javasctipt.js`, then the `load` request might look for `/ressources/ressources/partial.jsp` due to the relative URL.

Idea 2: Have you tried omitting the `<!DOCTYPE html>` in your partial JSP?

Comment: the partial is loded,just the jstl is not executing